# PHP Open and save files in non-utf8 (Windows-1256) encoding

Tags: php, html, file, encoding, utf-8

There are about 5000 `.htm` files on our website. These files are in Windows-1256 encoding. We need to add some javascript code at the beginning of these files. the problem is I can't open, edit and save the file because it causes the text format to be destroyed so I must save the files in windows-1256 encoding not anything else.

It sounds PHP saves the files in UTF-8. Is it possible to save the files in Windows-1256?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be occurring because you are grabbing the contents of a windows-1256 encoded file and manipulating it inside a file that is UTF-8 encoded. Set the content-type of the PHP file before grabbing the `.htm` files

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1256');
$html = file_get_contents('your_file.htm');
```